# Filter view by current year

Tags: 2013, filter, view

I have a `Year` column and I already know that it's not possible to filter a view using `Year` `equals` `=YEAR([TODAY])` and use `[TODAY]` in calculated  columns does not work as expected.

Does there exist a workaround to filter the items accordingly to the current year?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the Filter settings of a View you can only use [Today] as is, you can do simple +- calculations but you can not use Functions.

*Remember: Do **not** add spaces in your View Filter calculations: **[Today]-7***

So you need to add **two** Calculated Columns calculating

**january1st**

```
=DATE(Year([YourDate]),1,1)
```

and **december31st**

```
=DATE(Year([YourDate]),12,31)
```

and then compare in your View Filter if [Today] is between those dates

Comment: you're missing a closing square bracket. Also, what format is the date parameter in? Does it need quotes?

Comment: I'm working with SharePoint 2013 and when I'm created a calculated column it doesn't accept me functions =DATE() neither =TEXT().... what can I use instead?
THANK YOU!

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use some workaround as mentioned below.

1) Create two calculated columns Start Year and End Year

2) Start Year `= DATE(YEAR([Expiry Date]),1,1)`

3) End Year `= DATE(YEAR([Expiry Date]),12,31)`

4) Create a View and Filter Condition will be

Start Year is Less Than or Equal to `[TODAY]`  AND End Year is Greater Than Equal To `[TODAY]`

Answer (score 2):

You can try this workaround:

1) Create a calculated column **StartYear** = DATE(YEAR([your date field]),1,1)

2) Create a calculated column **EndYear** = DATE(YEAR([Expiry Date]),12,31)

3) Create a View and Filter:

**StartYear is Less Than or Equal to [TODAY] AND EndYear is Greater Than Equal To [TODAY]**

[Source](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/79edabd8-fb5c-4bf0-a447-c5cdeb5b43ef/how-to-filter-a-list-view-with-current-year?forum=sharepointgeneral).

Answer (score 1):

My quick-n-easy approach to this it to create a calculated column called Year to extract a text Year value from the existing date field:

> =TEXT([your date field name],“yyyy”)

Then filter by Year column.  Usually if a client needs to filter data for current year, they'll need past and future years too, or a range.  They can still do that with this column.