# Filtering a Grouped By view by current year in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view, filter, list-view-threshold, grouping

I am aware of [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/180263/filter-view-by-current-year) and have done this multiple times before and it used to work fine. However, currently I am facing unexpected behavior and it's different in Modern and Classic views.

I have a list with 6500 items on SP 2010. Content approval is enabled. Default view is set up so it groups items by Approval Status column. No filters. Everything is working as expected.

I've migrated the list to SharePoint Online and to overcome the 5000 limit, I want to set up a filter on the default view based on Created column values being in the current year. I've created Start Year and End Year calculated columns and can confirm the calculations are as expected. I have double checked in another view (where Created column is greater than or equal to 01/01/2018) and can confirm that only 300 are returned by that view - so in other words, only 300 items have been created this year.

These are the results:

1. **View with Start Year < [Today] < End Year and Grouped by Approval Status**:

  Modern View: Something went wrong. The number of items inhe list exceeds the list view threshold [something something...]

  Classic View: This view cannot be displayed because it exceeds the list view threshold (5000 items) enforced by the administrator.

2. **View with Start Year < [Today] < End Year and not Grouped by any column**

  Modern View: Works fine. Returns 300 items.

  Classic View: This view cannot be displayed because it exceeds the list view threshold (5000 items) enforced by the administrator.

What gives? Can anyone shed any light on WHY is this happening and HOW to filter a view which has Grouping set up?