# How to filter list by Current Year and future?

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have found [this thread](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/180263/filter-view-by-current-year), but this is not really same as my case. For example, I have a column **Year**, let us say, I enter a project Year 2018, I could finish the project in 2018, but it is also possible that I won't finish it till 2019 or even 2020. But it does not matter, even it has not been finished and it is 2019 right now, when I filter it, I do NOT want the project shown up, since it was entered as 2018.

Right now it is 2019, I could enter 2020 in the Year column for upcoming project, so for custom view, I want this project to be shown.

So basically, the filter result should have **Year 2019 or greater than 2019** in the column input, SINCE it is year of 2019 today.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking about the filter dropdowns at the top of each column, or the filter feature of a View? Views do have a "greater than or equal to" option.

Comment: Or, are you asking about a View that always filters on the current year?

Answer (score 2):

[Today] returns the current date so you can filter view with formula

```
[Year] >= YEAR([Today])
```