# (another take on) Filtering Sharepoint view based on date range

Tags: sharepoint-online, filter, view, date

I know that the answer for this question is easy to find on the internet, including [this thread](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/180263/filter-view-by-current-year) - but the suggested solution doesn't work for me.

I need to create a view in a Sharepoint online list, for items created "this year."

This should be possible to done by creating one calculated column "StartYear" with the formula =DATE(Year([Created]),1,1) and then another calculated column "EndYear" with the formula =DATE(Year([Created]),12,31), and then the view should get dates between these calculations.

However, when I try to create the calculated column, I get "Something went wrong - Syntax error".

Maybe, just maybe, this has to do with my SPO site being in Swedish. For example, I cannot use the [Me] but must use the Swedish [Jag] for filtering on current user.

I have tried to use Swedish and all different options, but the result is the same for =DATUM(År([Skapad]),1,1) =DATUM(År([Created]),1,1)  =DATE(År([Created]),1,1) and so on

So maybe, the issue is something else.

Anyone got an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about Swedish but in German you have to use ; instead of , in Formulas. Maybe try that

Comment: Thanks, that worked :)

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned you "need to create a list" does this mean you really haven't started?

If so, I recommend this:
Create a Year Column and default it to the Year you want when you add data

Does that make sense?  This way you would tag every item with a Year
You can use excel formula to pull the years out of you dates in your dataset
example: Start Date is 7/1/2019 End Date is 8/1/2020.
Result in Excel is 2019 and 2020 so that would be entered in. Use a datasheet to paste in the data or use the Import App, then set your default to the Current Year

Comment: Thanks, I understand, but the list is created and populated with looots items :) Sandro above found a working solution.